# How do I access Nginx server block externally to get rid of "Error 404 Not Found"?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, configuration

I have Nginx installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS virtual machine (VM). I have put the same HTML file in default and another virtual server block (my_domain). I can access the HTML file locally in a browser via `locahost/my_file.html` and `http://my_domain/my_file.html`.

Now, I want to access the HTML file in `my_domain` from another machine (outside VM). To do so, I have added the VM's public IP to `etc/hosts` with `server_name`. I am trying to access the HTML file from another machine like this:

```
http://my_ip/my_domain/my_file.html
```

and getting the `Error 404 not found error`.

What is it that I am doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

I can externally access the default server block via `http://my_ip/my_file.html` but not the `my_domain` block.

Here is how the configuration files look like. Anything wrong here?

**my_domain**

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/my_domain/html;
        index my_file.html;

        server_name my_domain my_domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                autoindex on;
                autoindex_exact_size off;
        }
}
```

**default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index my_file.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put `my_domain` into the `http://my_ip/my_domain/my_file.html`? Use either  IP or domain name.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If I don't put `my_domain` then wouldn't Nginx be directing to the default block? My intentions are to use my_domain without bothering the default one..

Comment: Yes, you are right, but why are you trying to use both IP and domain simultaneously? It should be either `http://my_ip/my_file.html` or `http://my_domain/my_file.html`, using `http://my_ip/my_domain/my_file.html` it will be request to the server `my_ip` with the request URI `/my_domain/my_file.html`.

Comment: If I don't use `my_ip` in browser.. how it will do GET request to my_file.html that is in another (virtual) machine? As said, `http://my_domain/my_file.html` works locally (within VM), but when i do it from another machine.. it doesn't..

Comment: I don't understand. Is your `my_domain` domain name resolves to your VM public IP?

Comment: It should, but it doesn't.. even though i put my_ip with server_name in `etc/hosts`.

Comment: Looks like it is some other problem unrelated to nginx. You can check nginx behavior with `curl` explicitly specifying the `Host` header: `curl -H 'Host: my_domain' http://my_ip/my_file.html`

Comment: I got this after doing curl, `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my_domain'` :/

Comment: `curl` should not try to resolve `my_domain` using the above command. `my_ip` should be VM public IP, not the domain name. Domain name is used only for the `Host` header.